# How to sign value to a field in BizForm in Kentico 8.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I am new to Kentico. The version I'm using is 8.2.

I have a form say ProductForm.

There are 5 fields(WeekDay, TimeFrame, ID, etc.) and 2 of these 5 are not visible to users but only exist in the database tabel (StartDate and EndDate).

The StartDate and EndDate depend on the selected WeekDay and TimeFrame.

Now, my problem is:
I have to prepare the values for both StartDate and EndDate before saving data.

```
  protected void bfCallBack_OnBeforeSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var topic = this.ddlTopic.SelectedValue;
        SetValue("Topic", topic);

        // Set the StartDate and EndDate
        ........
        #endregion Time Part

        #region Date Part
       ........

        #endregion Date Part

        var start = this.bfCallBack.FormInformation.GetFormField("StartDate");
        start.SetValue("StartDate", startTime);

        var end = this.bfCallBack.FormInformation.GetFormField("EndDate");
        end.SetValue("EndDate", startTime);


    }
```

I have tried 2 ways to set the values to these 2 fields :

Approach 1:

```
 var start = this.bfCallBack.FormInformation.GetFormField("StartDate");
 start.SetValue("StartDate", startTime);
```

Approach 2:

```
SetValue("StartDate", startTime);
```

But none of them work. I checked the database table and found that beside, these 2 fields, the rest of other fields all got values.

### Update

Here is the BizForm I use on my widget:

```
<cms:BizForm runat="server" ID="bfCallBack" SiteName="MySite" FormName="CallBack" OnOnAfterSave="bfCallBack_OnAfterSave" OnOnBeforeSave="bfCallBack_OnBeforeSave"></cms:BizForm>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
bfCallBack.Data.SetValue("StartDate", startTime)
```